# WordPress post revisions not creating when updating a custom post type via WP REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I have a few custom post types that have several custom fields created using ACF. I have enabled post revisions for the custom post type.

When I editing any field of a custom post using the admin dashboard and saving, the revision is created without any issues.

When I edit or update any field of the same post via WP REST API, the values are getting updated but revision history is not getting created.

It seems the only way revision history is created when using the dashboard and not via the REST API.

Is there a way to make it create revisions when updating or creating custom post type posts via REST API? Any hacks or hook I can use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
add_action('post_updated', 'wp_save_post_revision', 10);
```

Comment: According to WP support, revision history is not created if only post meta is updated via rest API. it’s not seen as an “update” for which a revision should be created.  When you update from the dashboard, the entire post data set is sent to the server so it’s seen as an update even when no post table data had changed.

Comment: What code / hook / function can I use to save the post or save post revision when only post meta is updated via the API.